# Why it shows getting previous data whenever I navigate to details screen using react navigation, useeffect, and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, use-effect

I am trying to build a movie details react native app with expo and whenever I'm trying to navigate from home to details page, every time it shows me previous data on movie details page. How to solve this issue.
I am using react navigation to navigate between screens and also I'm using axios to get data from and api.
I didn't understand, why every time it shows previous data.

Preview in video- https://www.youtube.com/shorts/0JgL2SPyujw

DetailsScreen.js-  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qLE1.png

```
const DetailsScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
    const [apis, setApis] = useState([]);
    const URL = "https://demoapi.com" + route.params.categoryWithId;
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Top ==>" + URL);
        async function getAllData() {
            try {
                const apis = await axios.get(URL);
                setApis(apis.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        getAllData();
    }, []);

    if (!apis.length) return null;
    console.log("details ==> " + JSON.stringify(apis));

    return (
        <>
            <ImageBackground source={{ uri: apis[0].image }} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.backgroundImage} >
                <Wrapper>
                    {/* PlatformLogo */}
                    <ImageBackground
                        resizeMode="contain"
                        source={{
                            uri: "https://pngimg.com/uploads/netflix/netflix_PNG32.png",
                        }}
                        style={styles.platformLogo}
                    />
                    <Title>{apis[0].title}</Title>
                    {/* <Text>{verticlebanner}</Text> */}
                    <SubTitle>{apis[0].date}</SubTitle>
                    <PlayIcon
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: "white",
                            borderRadius: 50,
                        }}
                    />
                </Wrapper>
            </ImageBackground>

            <StatusBar hidden />
        </>
    );
};
```

when I click on "minions" then details screens shows "dr. strange" and I click on "the ledge" then it shows data of "minions" and so on...
why it shows previous data every times

Answer (score 0):

As per your code it only required lodader or isLoading state for api call and state update as shown in below code it works fine for me.

```
const DetailsScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
const [apis, setApis] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const URL = "https://demoapi.com" + route.params.categoryWithId;
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Top ==>" + URL);
  getAllData();
}, []);
const getAllData = async () => {
try {
  const apis = await axios.get(URL);
  setApis(apis.data);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
 } finally {
   setIsLoading(false);
 }
 }
  if (!apis.length) return null;
console.log("details ==> " + JSON.stringify(apis));
 return (
<>
  {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator size={'large'} color={'#113A69 '} />
    : <>
      <ImageBackground source={{ uri: apis[0].image }} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.backgroundImage} >
        <Wrapper>
          {/* PlatformLogo */}
          <ImageBackground
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={{
              uri: "https://pngimg.com/uploads/netflix/netflix_PNG32.png",
            }}
            style={styles.platformLogo}
          />
          <Title>{apis[0].title}</Title>
          {/* <Text>{verticlebanner}</Text> */}
          <SubTitle>{apis[0].date}</SubTitle>
          <PlayIcon
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "white",
              borderRadius: 50,
            }}
          />
        </Wrapper>
      </ImageBackground>
      <StatusBar hidden />
    </>
  }
</>
);
 };
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it's not working for me. Still shows previous data. Is it possible to clear the previous state before render or pop the details screen's navigation?
If so then suggest me the correct code.